# Android: SlidingDrawer with bottomOffset and content visible

Tags: android-layout, android

I have been experiencing some issue with the SlidingDrawer in Android. I am building a screen with a horizontal sliding drawer. It is working fine, it is opening and closing as expected. I have set a bottomOffset as 50dip in order to see 50dpi of the content when the drawer is closed, but this is not happening.

When the drawer is closed, I am seeing the 50dip distance between the right side of the screen to the handle, but then the content view gets invisible so there is a 50dip black space between the handle and the screen edge, as the image below shows:

[image]

When I press the handle button, it seems that the content gets its visibility changed to visible, and then it appers. I would like to keep the content visible without having to press the handle, like in the imagem below:

[image]

I downloaded the SlidingDrawer source code from http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/ in order to try to change the code and get the expected result, but I am not getting.

The XML for the sliding drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<br.com.dina.partial.example.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/br.com.dina.partial.example"
    android:id="@+id/map_slider" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    my:handle="@+id/Handle"
    my:content="@+id/ViewLayout"
    my:direction="rightToLeft"        
    my:bottomOffset="-65dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test">

    <Button android:id="@+id/Handle" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="handle"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ViewLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar 
            android:id="@+id/actionbar" 
            style="@style/ActionBar"/>     

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/ViewContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</br.com.dina.partial.example.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Many thanks

edited to add the xml

Comment: Could you post the XML of the SlidingDrawer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onDrawerScrollListener`, `onDrawerOpenListener`, and `onDrawerCloseListener` to change the visibility of certain items depending on the state of the drawer. So when you say "the drawer is closed...and the content view is invisible" then in your `onDrawerCloseListener` set the content view to `VISIBLE`. Give this a try and let me know how it goes.

**EDIT** so you did something like this?:

```
drawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed() {
            //get the ViewContent by id and set visibility to VISIBLE
    });
```

Comment: Hi @koopaking3, I tried what you said, but it doesnt work. I dont know where the content view is going or what is happening to it, but it just doesnt get displayed. Thank you

Comment: I added sample code above...so you did something similar to this and it didn't work?

Comment: Hi @koopaking3, yes, I did the same thing and it is not working. It seems that the problem does not reside on the content visibility, but in the content position (I think).